# How to force ActiveStorage::Attached#attach to run synchronously -- disable async behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Is there anyway that I can force this method, [ActiveStorage::Attached#attach](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/Many.html#method-i-attach) to *not* enqueue a background job? In other words, I would like to disable the async behavior which seems to be included in `ActiveStorage::Attached#attach` so that the method executes synchronously and not asynchronously with either [ActiveJob](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) or something like [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to your question? I also would like to know if it is possible.

Comment: I did not unfortunately. if I do I will provide an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work currently:

```rb
def sync_attach(record, name, attachable)
  blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_and_upload!(
    io: attachable.open, filename: attachable.original_filename
  )
  blob.analyze
  attached = record.send(name)
  attached.purge
  attached.attach(blob)
end

# Given
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one_attached :image
end

# You can do
thing = Thing.create!
sync_attach(thing, :image, attachable)
```

You should also include mirroring in the method if you use that.

I welcome and seek any warnings, corrections, additions, etc. This is the best I've come up with so far.

Comment: Calling `attached.analyze` after the `attach` should do it and no need for the `purge` before the `attach` either.